# Overwrite span styles

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS !

I would like to overwrite a span style using external CSS. Any suggestions?

!important did not work for me.
Sample code below.

```
 <div class="abc" id= "xy" style="font-size: 30px;">
  <span style="color: #009530;">bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz bananaaa</span>      </div>
```

basically I would like to overwrite the #009530 for the text using a external css.

I tried like below external css. It did not work for me.

```
  #xy {
        color: blue !important;
      }
```

TIA

Comment: You are trying to change the color of the text in the div, not the span. Put an id in the span and point to it instead of the div id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following css:

```css
#xy span{
    color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc" id="xy" style="font-size: 30px;">
    <span style="color: #009530;">bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz bananaaa</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="xy" style="color: #009530;">bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz bananaaa</span>
```

css

```
 #xy 
 {
    color: blue !important;
 }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: He said he wanted to edit the span with CSS, so I figured the most direct way would be adding the id in the CSS directly to the element he wanted to change

Comment: `I would like to overwrite a span style using external CSS` did you read this?

Comment: there, i've also included his css to be more explicit

Comment: At least explain your answer. If the OP could figure it out just by looking, they probably wouldn't be asking the question in the first place.